# Queries on a string

Tags: c++, string

It's a B problem in codeforces
http://www.codeforces.com/problemset/problem/598/B
and i submit this code, but i get Wrong Answer.
It's brute force nothing special, but iam new at problem solving.

```
    #include <iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{

    char x[10000];
    scanf_s("%s",x);

    int num;
    scanf_s("%d",&num);

    int *l  = new int[num]; 
    int *r  = new int[num]; 
    int *k  = new int[num]; 
    for(int i =0;i<num;i++)
    {
        scanf_s("%d,%d,$d",&l[i],&r[i],&k[i]);
    }


    char temp;
    for(int i =0; i<num;i++)
    {
    for (int j =0;j<k[i];i++)
    {
     temp= x[l[i]-1];
     x[l[i]-1]=x[r[i]-1];
     x[r[i]-1]=temp;
    }
    }

  printf("%s",x);
return 0;
}
```

Any idea what is wrong or does it need to be optimized ?Is there better way to handle with case of many queries entered ?

Comment: You don't optimize code that does not compile.

Comment: The compilation errors are most likely due to warnings which are treated as errors. Do you look into warnings your compiler is giving you? For example, your usage of `scanf` is totally wrong.

Comment: scanf into a string? yeah that'll go well....

Comment: Expanding on @Borgleader 's comment. `scanf` is a C function. `string` is a C++ data type. C++ can often use C datatypes, but it is very rare that C can use C++ datatypes. Replace the `scanf` with `cin >> x` and go all C++. Alternative is to eschew C++ and `scanf` into `char x[appropriate size goes here]`. Don't know the appropriate size? That's going to be a problem in C.

Comment: In `scanf("%d",num);`, `scanf` requires a pointer to `num`, the location of `num` so that it can update the value stored at `num`. The remaining problems are variations on the preceding two problems.

Comment: There are no warnings and it's compiled. I edited the question it was a Runtime error in test case not compilation error .

Comment: You all mention scanf with string , what is the problem? try it.

Comment: You need to turn up the warning level.

Comment: @Gemy, what's your compiler? What is your command line to compile?

Comment: @user4581301 How to do that? sorry i don't understand you .

Comment: @SergeyA I use Visual studio 2012

Comment: @Gemy, you can refer to following link on how to change warning levels: http://mihai-nita.net/2010/05/10/changing-default-vs-warning-level/

Answer (score 1):

`scanf` is a C function. `string` is a C++ data type. C++ can often use C datatypes, but it is very rare that C can use C++ datatypes. `scanf` was written about 20 years before C++ existed and has no clue what a `string` is.

Next, `scanf` takes a [variable arguments list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function). It has no clue if the parameter types are correct and cannot easily check. It assumes that the programmer knows what they are doing.

End result, it tries to place `char` data as specified by the `%s` format option into a `string`. The `string` is written over with incompatible data [and undefined behaviour occurs.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Replace the `scanf` with

```
cin >> x;
```

and go all C++. Alternative is to eschew C++ and go C style:

```
char x[appropriate size goes here];
scanf("%s",x);
```

Don't know the appropriate size? That's going to be a problem. `string` resizes to fit. The `char` array expected by `scanf` cannot. If you read more data than you can fit, Undefined Behaviour.

In

```
scanf("%d",num);
```

`%d` says the programmer passed in a pointer to an integer, in this case it would be the location of `num` so that `scanf` can update the value stored at `num` with whatever was read. The value of `num` was passed in. `scanf` assumes this is a pointer and Undefined Behaviour results. Most likely whatever uninitialized garbage value that is in `num` is used as a memory location and some unsuspecting block of memory gets overwritten. This will cause problems at some point in the future when you actually need the data that was at that memory.

```
scanf("%d",&num);
```

or in C++

```
cin >> num;
```

The remaining problems are variations on the preceding two problems.

```
scanf("%d,%d,%d",l[i],r[i],k[i]);
```

needs pointers

```
scanf("%d,%d,%d",&l[i],&r[i],&k[i]);
```

and

```
printf("%s",x);
```

wants a `char` array, not a `string`.

```
printf("%s",x.c_str());
```

gets the `char` array equivalent to the `string`.

Recommendation: Compile with a higher level of intolerance to errors that the compiler can survive. In g++ I use at least `-pedantic -pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra -Werror`.

On a logical front, your input is all unchecked. A user could type in "rutabaga" for `num` with possibly comical results as your program tries to deal with non-numeric input. Again Undefined Behaviour. The program could crash. It could lock up. It could impregnate a male Llama.

In C++

```
if (cin >> num)
```

will catch some but not all forms of bad input. If this test fails, the contents of `num` are undefined and should not be used. Further, the stream will be in an error state and unreadable until the error is acknowledged and cleared. In C the equivalent is

```
if (scanf("%d",&num) == 1)
```

if `scanf` read exactly one value, `num`, all is good. Any other number of values read means `scanf` did not succeed and the contents of `num` are undefined.

Comment: ok , i will try this. I just want to clarify thing that i use printf and scanf because cin & cout is much slower and there is time limits in testcases .Sometimes i get wrong answer because of using cin & cout.
Thanks for your notes.

Comment: Although the main reason i post this question not to know how to use printf and scanf ,this is not the main problem. I just asked for the idea itself to solve the problem i mentioned above. I updated your notes in my code.

Comment: Stream IO is only slower when used incorrectly. Turn off stdout synch with `std::cout.sync_with_stdio(false);` and fear `endl` because it forces flushing. After that, usually performance is about the same unless the library is implemented poorly.